# Regular expression search in files, in the Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio, regex

I was trying to search for ".IsSet", but not "DocumentState.IsSet", in VS 2008 using regular expression search. How do I compose the regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you want to search for every *\.IsSet except for when it begins with "DocumentState"? I think that is somewhat advanced...

Comment: Right, I'm searching for not begin with "DocumentState"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~(DocumentState)\.IsSet
```

will match all `.IsSet` instances that do not follow `DocumentState`. To match exactly `.IsSet` but not `.IsSetFoo`, you can either use

```
~(DocumentState)\.IsSet>
```

or check the *Match whole word* option.

See [*Regular Expressions (Visual Studio)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) for a list of regular expression tokens supported in the Visual Studio search.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
(?!<DocumentState)\.IsSet
```

The ?!< is a "negative lookbehind".

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
^\.IsSet
```

^ : means beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can with the VS Search, but you can

1. Replace DocumentState.IsSet by a token (like "DOCSTATE")
2. Replace all .IsSert
3. Replace your token "DOCSTATE" with DocumentState.IsSet